# PhpStorm crashing whilst indexing Laravel

Tags: laravel, crash, phpstorm, homestead

I am running a 5 or 6-year-old Dell laptop the Inspiron 3521 with Ubuntu 14.04 - yes I know it's old.

I have been using PhpStorm on small projects with no issues. However I am just getting into Laravel and have initially it up on a virtual machine with Laravel Homestead. All good so far: I can view the base Laravel website on my host machine.

Now I think to myself lets create a project using the synced Laravel directory on my host machine as the base. This is where I run into trouble. Crash Crash Crash. I thought at first the issue was that I had opened PhpStorm as a user with insufficient permissions for the directory and the files. So I deleted the .Phpstorm config and system files. No joy.

Could it be a memory issue I asked myself being an older machine - I had not had this problem previously when using PhpStorm. So I enabled some Swap memory.

I am at this point baffled and will think about using Sublime or some other IDE.

Anyone out there have a similar experience. Am I going about something in the wrong way looking to create a project with the synced directory, is there a more clever way of going about this?

[Here is the Java error log](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AkgXXJOup_69rqW782yblaRc51vq8-dE) hope it makes sense to someone :)

Comment: Since it's an app crash, I suggest to create support ticket (can be done via Help menu in PhpStorm or via link on their website, e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731)